# Converting decimal to fraction

Tags: java, split, double, decimal, fractions

I have a method that is converting a decimal (double value) into a fraction and putting the numerator and denominator values into an int[] of size 2.

Testing it works out fine for most values except when I hit `0.0001`. Then the return value is `1.0/1.0`.

The method:

```
private static int[] toFractionPos(double x){
    String[] parts = Double.toString(x).split("\\.");
    double den = Math.pow(10, parts[1].length()); //denominator
    double num = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]) * den + Double.parseDouble(parts[1]); //numerator
    return reduceFraction((int)num, (int)den);
}
```

`reduceFraction()` method:

```
public static int[] reduceFraction(int num, int den){
    int gcf = GCF(num, den); //greatest common factor
    int[] rf = {num/gcf, den/gcf};
    return rf;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps of precision errors?

Comment: A double value is not a decimal. It is a floating-point representation with binary digits. Nothing decimal about it whatsoever. Do you mean a number with a fractional part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm seems fine. However, using `double` is not suitable for this kind of problem, because precision decreases as the scale grows.

You should use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead. I've roughly modified your example so that it works with them, but I haven't taken care of details, i.e. parsing the `String` shouldn't be necessary since scale can be retrieved from a `BigDecimal` with a getter, you can configure different rounding modes, etc:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Sample {

    static int[] toFractionPos(BigDecimal x) {
        String[] parts = x.toString().split("\\.");
        BigDecimal den = BigDecimal.TEN.pow(parts[1].length()); // denominator
        BigDecimal num = (new BigDecimal(parts[0]).multiply(den)).add(new BigDecimal(parts[1])); // numerator
        return reduceFraction(num.intValue(), den.intValue());
    }

    static int[] reduceFraction(int num, int den) {
        int gcd = BigInteger.valueOf(num).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(den)).intValue(); // greatest
                                                                                   // common
                                                                                   // divisor
        int[] rf = { num / gcd, den / gcd };
        return rf;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] fraction = toFractionPos(new BigDecimal("0.0001"));
        System.out.println(fraction[0] + "/" + fraction[1]); // 1/10000
    }
}
```

*Note:* optimizations left as an excercise ;)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't work with doubles as you are losing precision and this can lead to serious errors. But in the case of `1.0001` the problem is that:

```
Double.toString(1.0001) == "1.0E-4"
```

Then you try to parse `"0E-4"` and you get 0 instead of 1. You could do the following if you expect at most 10 decimal points:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0", 
    DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(10);
String[] parts = df.format(x).split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
private static int[] toFractionPos(double x){
  int den = (int)Math.pow(10,(int)Math.log10(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
  int num = (int)(x*den);
  return reduceFraction(num, den);//this came from your code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work,

```
public int[] Fraction(double n) {
   BigDecimal p = BigDecimal.ONE;
   BigDecimal dn = BigDecimal.valueOf(n);       
   while(true){
        dn = dn.multiply(p);
        if( dn.compareTo(new BigDecimal(dn.toBigInteger()))==0 )
            break;
        else
            p = p.multiply(BigDecimal.TEN);
   }
   BigInteger num=dn.toBigInteger(), den=p.toBigInteger(), g=num.gcd(den);
   num = num.divide(g);
   den = den.divide(g);             
   int[] res = new int[2];
   res[0] = num.intValue();
   res[0] = den.intValue();
   return res;
}
```

Comment: This does **not** answer the question in a useful way. _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong.

Comment: I edited my comment to answer the question in useful way.